# Get child product categories from parent product category in WooCommerce

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

In WooCommerce, I am trying to get all child product category terms from the parent term id of the current product category with the code below:

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$category_parent_id = $category->parent;
$category_test = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false] );
```

The variable `$category_parent_id` returns the parent product category id and `$category_test` returns all product category terms

I'm trying to return all child product categories using the parent product category term id retrieved from `$category->parent`

Logically I tried:

```
$category_test = $category_parent_id->get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false] );
```

and

```
$category_test = $category->parent->get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false] );
```

But this didn't give me back all child categories of the current parent category.
Anyone have any idea if and if so how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited (1)**

You will need to use `'child_of'` from `WP_Term_Query` available arguments, that will let you to get all child terms for the current product category **parent** term:

```
// Only on product category archive pages
if( is_product_category() ) {
    $main_term = get_queried_object();

    $args_query = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
        'hide_empty' => false, 
        'child_of' => $main_term->parent
    );

    if ( $main_term->parent != 0 ) {
        // Loop through WP_Term Objects
        foreach ( get_terms( $args_query ) as $term ) {
            if( $term->term_id != $main_term->term_id ) {
                // $term->slug; // Slug

                // Output each (linked) term name…
                echo sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a></br>', get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ), $term->name );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can also use `get_term_children()` like:

```
// Only on product category archive pages
if( is_product_category() ) {
    $main_term  = get_queried_object();
    $taxonomy   = 'product_cat';

    if ( $main_term->parent != 0 ) {
        $child_ids = get_term_children( $main_term->parent, $taxonomy );

        echo '<ul>';

        foreach ( $child_ids as $child_id ) {
            if( $child_id != $main_term->term_id ) {
                $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child_id, $taxonomy );
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child_id, $taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

This **is only for product category archive pages**, as for product pages you can have many product categories set for a product and the code will be complicated and quiet different…

Comment: This indeed gives all desired raw data output. Any idea on just to output the name and or slug for example?

Comment: Just accepted, if u could find the time to explain just to output name and or slug instead of raw data that would save me hours of searching. If not thanks anyhow :)

Comment: @Jeroen_L I have updated my code to output name and or slug…

Comment: Just noticed it won't take the parent if on a product page.
And it also grabs parents of parents. and the children of those parents...
any ideas? ill share my new code in next post if u are interested.

Comment: @Jeroen_L I have edited my answer with some other code … Now on product page this is completelly different as a product can have many product categories…

Comment: ill need to check it but it's getting late, what if on product page (is_product) will it also work then?
Ill check it tomorrow, thanks so far tho.

Comment: @Jeroen_L The code just handle product category archive pages as you can have many product categories set for a product… So it will be something really different and more complicated to handle product pages and you should ask a new question to handle product pages…

Comment: Almost....

First tests show that it only goes up 1 level now but if any of the brothers or sisters inside that level have any subcategories then those subcategories are shown also. 

It actually does this now, go up 1 lvl (parent category) grab all categories there (which is what i need) but if any of those categories have subcategories those will be taken 2.

So it goes +1 now to goto parent and will keep going -1 then as long as possible, how can we prevent it from doing the -1?

For the Product pages, is it easier if products is restricted to 1 associated category?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue of grabbing sub categories as in cousins by parsing in the parent category id and combining other solutions together. ill update my own answer with the new code. all that is left now is how to grab the list on product page if we know the parent category id