# Get child product categories from parent product category for CUSTOM TAXONOMY archive page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, mysql, wpdb

Can anyone help me as [LoizTheAztec](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/79855/loictheaztec) pretty much covered most of what I need here with his very [helpful answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/361045/get-child-product-categories-from-parent-product-category-in-woocommerce/361046#361046). What I need to do is alter this further, and rather than it being on a Product Cat Archive page, I need it to do the same thing on a custom taxonomy page ( a hierarchical custom taxonomy ), and to only show product categories ( terms ) for that custom taxonomy if the product cats ( terms ) are in the custom taxonomy. So it would be a query using two taxonomies.

I have achieved what I need another way, with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622017/get-woocommerce-product-categories-that-contain-a-specific-product-brand/61624358#61624358), that uses wpdb ( efficient ) but thereafter, I use get_term_by quite a few times to search through the array of results. ( inefficient ).

I don't think it is possible, and I am not too familiar with how I could achieve it using wpdb for each section. I think it is a type of recursion, and I am not entirely sure how to achieve this as mysql is a relational database. I have tried the WITH command with mysql that throws an error so I don't think recursion is possible in wordpress, unless you want to use a bunch of inefficent foreach loops.

This is the layout of the page with tabs for each product category that I want to show, Each product category shows the CHILD product categories ( it's descendants ) for the particular custom taxonomy object :

Custom Taxonomy Archive Page
[image: Each parent product category shows the CHILD product categories ( it's descendants ) for the particular custom taxonomy object; each tab will have different child categories]

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */
/**
 * THIS TEMPLATE IS FOR DISPLAYING WORKPLACES
 * IT FINDS PRODUCT CATEGORIES FROM EACH SECTION AND SHOWS THEM IF THEY ARE RELEVANT FOR THE WORKPLACE.
 * 
 */
defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

get_header('shop');

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action('woocommerce_before_main_content');

?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header background_diamond">
    <script>
    var $gg = jQuery.noConflict();
    $gg(document).ready(function() {

        $gg(".custom_content").shorten();
    });

    
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .major_cat_archive.custom_banner_style::before {
        <?php $term = get_queried_object();

        
// vars
$image = get_field('banner_image', $term);

if ($image)
{

?>background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);
            <?php
}

elseif (!$image)
{
?>background-image: url(<?php woocommerce_category_image();
}

?>);
    }
    </style>
    <?php if (apply_filters('woocommerce_show_page_title', true)): ?>
        
    <div class="major_cat_archive custom_banner_style example_layout_left">

        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title example_layout" data-aos="fade-right"
            data-aos-offset="-200" data-aos-delay="10" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-easing="ease"
            data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="false" data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center">
            <?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php
endif; ?>
    <?php
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
 */
do_action('woocommerce_archive_description');

//echo '<pre>';
      //  var_dump( $term );
      //  echo '</pre>';
?>
</header>
<div class="holder " data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="-200" data-aos-delay="10" data-aos-duration="1000"
    data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="false" data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center">
    <div class="sub_holder row content">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="intro_sec">
                <div class="sub_holder row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 f-col">
                        <div class="first_col">
                            <h2>Our Value Promise</h2>
                            <div class="custom_content">
                                <?php $term = get_queried_object();
$custom_content = get_field('custom_content', $term);
echo $custom_content; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">

<?php
                    $image = get_field('workplace_thumb', $term);

if ($image)
{
?>
                        <div class="second_col" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);">

                        <?php
}

elseif (!$image)
{?>
                        <div class="second_col" style="background-image: url(<?php woocommerce_category_image();
}

?>);">
                            <div class="gradient_overlay"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container notices">
    <div class="row_notices">
        <?php /*notices output in separate div */
?>
        <div class="xoo-wsc-cart-trigger">Trigger Side Cart</div>
        <?php
    do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container cat_view">
    <div class="row"><?php


   $workplace_term_slug = $term->slug; // A term slug is required (not the term id or term name)

   


$workplace_term_slug = $term->slug; // A term slug is required (not the term id or term name)

 $results = get_product_categories_from_a_product_workplace( $workplace_term_slug );


   if( ! empty($results) ) {
   
       $term_names = []; // Initializing an empty array variable
   
       // Loop through each product category terms:
       foreach ( $results as $result ) {
           $term_id   = $result->term_id; // Term id
           $term_name = $result->slug; // Term slug
           $term_slug = $result->name; // Term name
           $taxonomy  = 'product_cat'; 
   
           $term_link = get_term_link( get_term( $result->term_id, $taxonomy ), $taxonomy );
   
           // Example: Set the linked formatted term name in an array
           $term_names[] = '<a class="'.$result->slug.'" href="'.$term_link.'">'.$result->name.'</a>';
           $cats1[] = $result->slug;
         //  $cats1 = array_unique( $cats1 );
       }   
       $term_names = array_unique( $term_names );
       echo count( $term_names );

       
   
       // Display the linked formatted terms names
       //echo '<div class="workplace-categories '.$workplace_term_slug.'">'.implode(' ', $term_names).'</div>';
       echo '<pre> Every PRODUCT CAT term in this TAXONOMY object ';
       print_r( $cats1 );
       echo '</pre>';
   }


   

    /*at this point, all relevant category slugs have been gathered and then sorted to remove duplicates.*/

 
        
/**
 * INITIALISE EMPTY ARRAYS FOR PROCESSING.
 * ADD TO ARRAY IF SLUG AT $check IS A SIBLING OF RELEVANT CATEGORY.
 * IT ALSO WILL CHECK WITH || OR IF IT IS == TO RELEVANT CATEGORY.
 * THIS IS IN THE EVENT A PRODUCT IS ASSIGNED TO THE PARENT CATEGORY.
 * EACH ARRAY IS PLACED WITHIN IT'S RELEVANT TAB.
 * AN 'OTHER' TAB WILL ONLY APPEAR IF A CATEGORY IS ABSTRACT TO THE RELEVANT CATEGORIES.
 * THIS USES workplace_construct_categories(); & prod_cat_is_ancestor_of(); FUNCTIONS IN FUNCTIONS.PHP.
 */

 /*Initialise each relevant array */
    $array_of_window_cleaning = [];
    $array_of_hygiene_products = [];
    $array_of_catering_supplies = [];
    $array_of_hygiene_equipment = [];
    $array_of_workwear = [];
    $abstract_categories = [];
    
if( $cats1 ){
    foreach ($cats1 as $check)
    {
        $value = get_term_by('slug', $check, 'product_cat');
        $workwear_safety = get_term_by('slug', 'workwear-safety', 'product_cat');
        $hygiene_products = get_term_by('slug', 'hygiene-products', 'product_cat');
        $hygiene_equipment = get_term_by('slug', 'hygiene-equipment', 'product_cat');
        $catering_supplies = get_term_by('slug', 'catering-supplies', 'product_cat');
        $window_cleaning = get_term_by('slug', 'window-cleaning', 'product_cat');

        if (prod_cat_is_ancestor_of($workwear_safety, $value) || ($value->slug == $workwear_safety->slug))
        {
            if ($value->slug != $workwear_safety->slug)
                $array_of_workwear[] = $value->slug;
        }
    
        elseif (prod_cat_is_ancestor_of($hygiene_products, $value) || ($value->slug == $hygiene_products->slug))
        {
            
            if ($value->slug != $hygiene_products->slug)
                $array_of_hygiene_products[] = $value->slug;
                
        }
    
        elseif (prod_cat_is_ancestor_of($hygiene_equipment, $value) || ($value->slug == $hygiene_equipment->slug))
        {
            if ($value->slug != $hygiene_equipment->slug)
                $array_of_hygiene_equipment[] = $value->slug;
        }
    
        elseif (prod_cat_is_ancestor_of($catering_supplies, $value) || ($value->slug == $catering_supplies->slug))
        {
            if ($value->slug != $catering_supplies->slug)
                $array_of_catering_supplies[] = $value->slug;
        }
    
        elseif (prod_cat_is_ancestor_of($window_cleaning, $value) || ($value->slug == $window_cleaning->slug))
        {
            if ($value->slug != $window_cleaning->slug)
                $array_of_window_cleaning[] = $value->slug;
        }
    
        else
        {   
                $abstract_categories[] = $value->slug;
            
        }
    }
    } 

?>




    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<pre><?php
//print_r( $array_of_hygiene_products );
?></pre>
<!-- Display section of categories -->

<div class="container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="-300" data-aos-delay="10" data-aos-duration="1000"
    data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="false" data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="main_headings cat_titles"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?>: Relevant Categories </h2>
    </div>
</div> <?php
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
                <li class="active" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="-300" data-aos-delay="10"
                    data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="true"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"><a class="active" href="#tab1" data-bs-toggle="tab">Workwear
                        & Safety</a></li>
                <li data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="-300" data-aos-delay="300" data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="true"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"><a href="#tab2" data-bs-toggle="tab">Hygiene Products</a>
                </li>
                <li data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="-300" data-aos-delay="600" data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="true"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"><a href="#tab3" data-bs-toggle="tab">Hygiene Equipment</a>
                </li>
                <li data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="-300" data-aos-delay="900" data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="true"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"><a href="#tab4" data-bs-toggle="tab">Catering Supplies</a>
                </li>
                <li data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="-300" data-aos-delay="1200" data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="true"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"><a href="#tab5" data-bs-toggle="tab">Window Cleaning</a></li>
                <?php
    if (!empty($abstract_categories))
    {
?>
                <li class="tab6_zindex" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="-300" data-aos-delay="1200" data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="true"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"><a href="#tab6" data-bs-toggle="tab">More</a></li>
                <?php
    } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content container">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-parent=".tab-pane" href="#collapseOne">

                        Workwear & Safety
                    </a>
                </h4> 
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php $term = get_queried_object();
    $safteyworkwear = get_field('workwear-safety', $term);
    echo $safteyworkwear;

    //$newarray = [];
    sort_categories( $array_of_workwear ); 

?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-parent=".tab-pane" href="#collapseTwo">
                        Hygiene Products
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php $hyg_products = get_field('hygiene_products', $term);
    echo $hyg_products; 
  
    sort_categories( $array_of_hygiene_products );
?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-parent=".tab-pane" href="#collapseThree">
                        Hygiene Equipment
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php $hyg_equip = get_field('hygiene_equipment', $term);
    echo $hyg_equip;

   sort_categories( $array_of_hygiene_equipment ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-parent=".tab-pane" href="#collapseFour">
                        Catering Supplies
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php /*do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); */ ?>
                    <?php $catering = get_field('catering_supplies', $term);
    echo $catering;

    sort_categories( $array_of_catering_supplies ); 
?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-parent=".tab-pane" href="#collapseFive">
                        Window Cleaning
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php /*do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); */ ?>
                    <?php $win_cleaning = get_field('window_cleaning', $term);
    echo $win_cleaning;
    sort_categories( $array_of_window_cleaning ); 
?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--tab 5 close -->

    <?php
    if (!empty($abstract_categories))
    {
?>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-parent=".tab-pane" href="#collapseSix">
                        More
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php /*do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); */ ?>
                    <?php
                   
                   sort_categories( $abstract_categories ); 
?>
                </div><!-- close -->
            </div><!-- close -->
        </div><!-- close -->

     
    </div><!-- more div close -->


    
</div><!-- close -->







</div><!-- close -->
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo '</div>';
    } ?>

<!--end of display section -->
<?php
echo '<pre>';
  //  print_r( $array_of_hygiene_products);
    echo '</pre>';?>

<?php
   // woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10 removed
     */
    //do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop');


    
if (woocommerce_product_loop())
{

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */

}
else
{
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action('woocommerce_no_products_found');
}
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
 */
do_action('woocommerce_after_main_content');
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
get_footer('shop');
```

my function to sort the categories.
I was trying to paginate the sections ( haven't achieved this yet which is why I am trying to change my code and my reason for this question )

```
function sort_categories($cat_slugs){
    /**func att */
    if (!empty($cat_slugs))
        {
            global $wp_query;

           $cat_slugs = array_unique( $cat_slugs);
           $term_count = count( $cat_slugs );
           $per_page = 20;
           $max_num_pages = ceil( $term_count / $per_page );
           
          // var_dump( $max_num_pages );
           $page  = get_query_var('page');
           $paged = get_query_var('paged');
           $current_page = ($paged ? $paged : ($page ? $page : 1));
        $offset = (($current_page - 1) * $per_page);
    
        $ids = [];
        foreach($cat_slugs as $each){
            $testterm = get_term_by('slug', $each, 'product_cat');
            $id = $testterm->term_id;
            $ids[] = $id;
    
        }
     
       // print_r( $ids);
        $terms3 = 
            array(
                'orderby'    => 'id',
                'order'      => 'ASC',
              //  'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'hide_empty' => true,
                'include'    => $ids,
                'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
                'number' => $per_page,
                'offset' => $offset,
                'max_num_pages' => $max_num_pages,
            
        );
    
        $terms5 = get_terms('product_cat', $terms3);
        
      
     
            echo '<div class=" woocommerce columns-5"><ul id="custom_load" class=" products columns-5">';
       
            foreach ($terms5 as $check)
            {
                $check = $check->slug;
                $value = get_term_by('slug', $check, 'product_cat');           
                workplace_construct_categories($value);
               //wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product_cat' );
            }
    
        }
        if (!empty($terms5)){ echo '</ul>'; echo ''; echo next_posts_link('Next page', $max_num_pages ); 
}
```

```
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622017/get-woocommerce-product-categories-that-contain-a-specific-product-brand/61624358#61624358
 */

    function get_product_categories_from_a_product_workplace( $workplace_term_slug, $taxonomy = 'workplaces' ) {
        global $wpdb;
    
        return $wpdb->get_results( "
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
            FROM    {$wpdb->prefix}terms t1
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt1
                ON  t1.term_id = tt1.term_id 
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr1
                ON  tt1.term_taxonomy_id = tr1.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr2
                ON  tr1.object_id = tr2.object_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt2
                ON  tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id         
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t2
                ON  tt2.term_id = t2.term_id
            WHERE tt1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
            AND tt2.taxonomy = '$taxonomy'
            AND  t2.slug = '$workplace_term_slug' 
             
            
            
                 
        ", OBJECT );
    }
```

Comment: there is no code to work with in your question, please use the edit link to update your question so that it is complete and self contained. You can link to other things to support your question but it must be possible to understand and answer without those links

Comment: i had forgotten to add it thanks